# Name of design pattern where class's only job is just to ensure precondition and postcondition tasks are performed

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns

I have a class where I know exactly what it needs to do, but I can't think of a name to describe what it's doing.

I need to manage the behavior of a class called `TransformThread`.  It represents a thread with an Execute loop that chews up tasks off of a message queue.

I need to make sure that after submitting a batch of tasks, the parent thread waits for `TransformThread` to get a read lock on some shared objects before leaving scope.  The main thread can not leave scope until the child thread gets started.

My solution is to make a child class of `TransformThread`, let's say

```
class TransformThread {
  class LockHelper {
    TransformThread & _parent;

    // Tells the transform thread to start trying to get that read lock.
    LockHelper(TransformThread & parent);

    // Blocks main thread until the transform thread has its read lock.
    ~LockHelper();

    // Add a task to the threadsafe TransformThread queue.
    // This will be the only way to add tasks to a TransformThread since I don't want people adding tasks without afterwards blocking until the read lock is acquired.
    AddTransform (TransformTask const & foo);
  };

  LockHelper GetLockHelper () { return LockHelper(*this); }
};
```

`LockHelper` is a terrible name though. =(  What am I supposed to call this such that another programmer will see the class being used and have some clue of what it does without digging through the header?

Comment: You might have better luck with this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, this seems sort of off-topic for SO.

Comment: And to provide something constructive .. Observer? Hmm, no, impinges on observer/observable too much. Enforcer?